# Regex matching urls

Tags: php, regex

I'm using `\b(https?|ftp|file)://[-A-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;|]*[A-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]` to match urls in this string (added line breaks for ease of viewing; actual string is one long thing):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
http://www.google.com Nullam id lacus turpis.
http://www.google.com?test=correct&only=1 Quisque ac posuere sem.
http://www.google.com/search?q=blah|george.
```

My current regex gets the first two. For the third one it gets `http://www.google.com/search?q=blah|george`. How can I stop the match at the `|`? i.e., I want it to match only `http://www.google.com/search?q=blah`.

Answer (score 2):

Just take `|` out of the "allowed characters" character classes.

Comment: ... Seriously? You just click slightly to the right of the `|` character, hit Backspace, then repeat with the other ones.

Comment: If you don't know, please give up now

Comment: I mean I want it to do it automatically.

Comment: And I don't want to exclude only `|`. I want to exclude `|` and anything following it if `|` is right next to the url.

Comment: By not allowing `|` to be a part of the pattern, the match will stop if it finds one.

Comment: Ok... but how do I change my regex?

Comment: Please, just... if you can't figure out how to press the Backspace key with the cursor in the right position, just give up now. For the sake of humanity, just. Give. Up.